# trouble installing and successfully running ipython notebook

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter-notebook

I have installed python 3.3.0 and all the package dependencies from here for ipython and some other basic python libraries.

```
http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#ipython
```

However whenever I navigate the command prompt in windows 7 to the "C:\Python33\Scripts" directory and run the command:

```
ipython notebook --pylab inline
```

as suggested by this website (Open Tech School) It's not bringing up the ipython notebook in my web browser as it has normally done?:

```
http://opentechschool.github.io/python-data-intro/core/notebook.html
```

I can't think of what I might have done wrong: I installed python 3.3.0 and all the 3.3 binary installers from :

```
http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/
```

My path variable (right click on my computer select properties > Advanced system settings (left hand side) > Then the "Advanced" tab > Environment Variables:

My Path variable is in the lower "system variables" section? Does it need to be in the upper "User Variables" section as well? or instead of?

The contents of my Path "system variable" is:

```
%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Python33\Scripts;C:\Python33\
```

Please help me figure out why my ipython notebook installation is not opening in my default firefox web browser?

I get the error:

```
C:\Python33\Scripts>ipython notebook --pylab inline
'ipython' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Got further with trying ipython3 as suggested, but got the following error:

```
C:\Python33\Scripts>ipython3 notebook --pylab inline
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python33\Scripts\ipython3-script.py", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('ipython==1.2.1', 'console_scripts', 'ipython3')()
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\IPython\__init__.py", line 118, in start_i
python
    return launch_new_instance(argv=argv, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\IPython\config\application.py", line 544,
in launch_instance
    app.initialize(argv)
  File "<string>", line 2, in initialize
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\IPython\config\application.py", line 89, i
n catch_config_error
    return method(app, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\IPython\terminal\ipapp.py", line 312, in i
nitialize
    super(TerminalIPythonApp, self).initialize(argv)
  File "<string>", line 2, in initialize
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\IPython\config\application.py", line 89, i
n catch_config_error
    return method(app, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\application.py", line 373, in
 initialize
    self.parse_command_line(argv)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\IPython\terminal\ipapp.py", line 307, in p
arse_command_line
    return super(TerminalIPythonApp, self).parse_command_line(argv)
  File "<string>", line 2, in parse_command_line
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\IPython\config\application.py", line 89, i
n catch_config_error
    return method(app, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\IPython\config\application.py", line 474,
in parse_command_line
    return self.initialize_subcommand(subc, subargv)
  File "<string>", line 2, in initialize_subcommand
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\IPython\config\application.py", line 89, i
n catch_config_error
    return method(app, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\IPython\config\application.py", line 405,
in initialize_subcommand
    subapp = import_item(subapp)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\IPython\utils\importstring.py", line 42, i
n import_item
    module = __import__(package, fromlist=[obj])
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\IPython\html\notebookapp.py", line 38, in
<module>
    from jinja2 import Environment, FileSystemLoader
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\jinja2\__init__.py", line 33, in <module>
    from jinja2.environment import Environment, Template
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\jinja2\environment.py", line 13, in <modul
e>
    from jinja2 import nodes
ImportError: cannot import name nodes

C:\Python33\Scripts>
```

Comment: thanks for your suggestion, but i got another error as a result. Jinja2 which I believe installed properly?

Comment: i'm still getting the error: cannot import name nodes, which I assume is part of the jinja2 library?

Comment: thanks markupsafe and tornado dependencies fixed it.